# Taking a slice out of a string incorrectly C++

Tags: c++, function, slice, string-concatenation

I am attempting to write a function that outputs a string of 5 characters from a string of concatenated primes 1000 characters long starting at a point (n) the user specifies. I have finally gotten the program itself to compile but I seem to be running into errors in the program itself and we have not yet been taught of tools that would help me see where my issue is in my programming. I believe the issue is in getting and displaying the slice itself, not the concatenated string...but again, I may be/probably am wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

-Aspiring Computer Crim. Major

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


std::string get_concatenated_primes()
{
        unsigned int base, test, cap=1000, prime=0;
        std::string plist;
        for (base=0; base < cap; ++base)
        {
            for (test=2; test < base; ++test)
            {
                    if (base % test == 0)
                            break;
                    else
                    {
                            prime=1;
                    }
            }

            if (prime == 1 &&  plist.length() < 1000)
            {
                    plist += base;
            }
    }
    return plist;
}


std::string get_slice_of_5(const std::string concat_primes, const unsigned int n)
{
        std::string slice;
        slice = concat_primes.substr (n, 5);
        return slice;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int n;

    while(std::cin >> n)
    {
        std::string concat_primes = get_concatenated_primes();
        std::cout << get_slice_of_5(concat_primes, n) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it

Comment: For one thing, you never reset `prime` back to zero. You don't check that `n` is too large. Exactly what errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 998) > this->size() (which is 997)

I did not get what do you want to do, but you should check that concat_primes has more characters than n.